# Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop

Tags: uninstall

Installed Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop from usb boot flash I get a blank screen with 2 small icons at the bottom of the screen, then the rest starts to load, then after a while I get just a  corrupted screen, so I cant get any further and have to switch computer off I have tried new download still the same result.
Anyone help they say its as easy as 1 2 3 to use a USB install, I can get 1 then 2 but 3??
Thanks 
Pete

Comment: please state what the icons are and what you mean by "the rest starts to load"

Comment: Punctuation might help us understand this more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you're seeing the key-interrupt screen at the bottom (person / key prompt that allows a more advanced user to do more involved installations).

I would recommend you look, instead, at a live-CD/live-DVD option as I did.  On a USB install, I had all kinds of issues.  Once I used a DVD, it was no longer a problem and I've been loving 13.04 ever since.

Comment: Thanks for that I will try CD/live-DVD option and see how I go

Comment: Good luck, let us know if that fixes it!  It definitely worked for me.